# dynamically change size of multi-type elements

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, gridview, dynamic-sizing

I'm writing a script that is supposed to resize filtering-inputs based on width of a gridviews columns. It used to be only textboxes and I got it to work somewhat fine:
[image]

**the script:**

```
$("#<%= myGridView.ClientID %> th").each(function (index) {
    $('input[type="text"]:eq(' + index + ')').css('width', $(this).width() + 1.5);
    $('input[type="text"]:eq(' + index + ')').css('padding', '0');
});
```

Then It turned out that col-number 5 can only be a set ammount of values and should therefore be a dropdown list. So i figured I'd do something like this:

```
$("#<%= myGridView.ClientID %> th").each(function (index) {
    if (index === 5) {
        $('select').css('width', $(this).width() + 1.5);
        $('select').css('padding', '0');
    }
    else {
        $('input[type="text"]:eq(' + index + ')').css('width', $(this).width() + 1.5);
        $('input[type="text"]:eq(' + index + ')').css('padding', '0');
    }
});
```

Here is the result:
[image]

As you can see, not quite what I wanted.
Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**ASP was requested:**

```
--><input type="text" id="id1"/><!--Comments are needed to get rid of whitespace between text boxes
     --><input type="text" id="id2" /><!--
     --><input type="text" id="id3"/><!--
     --><%/*<input type="text" id="id4" />*/ %>
        <select>
            <option value="blank"></option>
            <option value="True">True</option>
            <option value="False">False</option>
        </select><!--
     --><input type="text" id="id5" /><!--
     --><input type="text" id="id6"/>
        <input type="button" id="clearFilters" value="Clear filters" style="position: relative; top: -3px; height: 19px; "/>
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="myGridView" runat="server" blablabla>etc.etc.</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `index == 5` by `index == 4` as index is zero based.

It seems there could be something else wrong, but probably we could help better if we see the html.

Comment: Yeah, solved part of the problem :P But i still get one textbox that covers the entire gridview and more